# What is difference between Config vs Operational vs Operations in Opendaylight REST API?

Tags: opendaylight

Config and Operational are the datastore in MD-SAL. So The first one is filled with the configuration information that users push through REST API. The second is the operational information that comes from the system. But what does Operations refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operations refers to yang-defined RPCs (ie Remote Procedure Calls) that can be invoked to perform some task.